# logic problems interesting

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There is a treasure chest with 0-1000 coins in it, uniformly distributed. You place a bid on the chest and if 1.5 times your bid is greater than whats in the chest, then you get chest. What is your optimal bid?

So value V and bid B gives expression 1.5V-B and I want to find B such that this is maximized?

Second question is if I play a game where there are 4 tiles total, 2 sets of pairs. The goal is to match both pairs. So I can flip over any two pair. What is my probability of winning? Do I want to go first? What if its 6 cards total, 2 sets of threes?

Comment: The expression $1.5V-B$ is not consistent with the description in the first paragraph. You win a value of $V$ if $V<1.5B$; do you also lose $B$ the amount that you bid, meaning that you net $V-B$? And what happens if $V\ge 1.5B$? Do you simply get nothing, or do you lose $B$?

Comment: I meant to say that the payoff is $1.5V - B$ if $B \ge V$ and 0 other wise.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, assuming from some of your statements that,  you win if $V < 1.5B$, the payoff is $V-B$ and that if you do not win you lose nothing (which is the best case scenario),

say you bid an amount of $0 \le B \le \frac{2000}{3}$.  There is no point bidding more.  Now if you win, then $V \in [0, 1.5B)$.
$E(V \mid B$ is winning bid$) = 0.75B$

Thus expected payoff for a winning bid $B$ is $-0.25B$, so best bet is not to bid anything (or $0$ if you must).

---

Addendum: If the payoff is $1.5V - B$ as later clarified, and win occurs only if $B \ge V$ (which is NOT what the statements seem to imply, then if you win, if $V \in [0, B]$.
Now $E(V \mid B$ is winning bid)$ = 0.5B$, and expected payoff is $1.5\times0.5B - B = -0.25B$ again.  So once again, don't bid / play.

I think they used to use the term "winner's curse" for such situations.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, if the first player flips a pair (probability $\frac 13$), he wins immediately.  Can you see how to guarantee a second player win if  he does not?  For two sets of three, what are the rules?  Does player 1 have to turn three cards, or can he stop if the first two don't match?

Answer (score 0):

Your return on a bid of $B$ is $$f_B(V)=\left(\frac32V-B\right)[B\ge V]\;,$$ when the value of the chest is $V$, where $[B\ge V]$ is an [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). Assuming that you must bid an integer amount, the expected return $E(B)$ on a bid of $B$ is

$$\begin{align*}
E(B)&=\frac1{1001}\sum_{V=0}^{1000}f_B(V)\\\\
&=\frac1{1001}\sum_{V=0}^{1000}\left(\frac32V-B\right)[B\ge V]\\\\
&=\frac1{1001}\sum_{V=0}^B\left(\frac32V-B\right)\\\\
&=\frac1{1001}\left(\sum_{V=0}^B\frac32V-B(B+1)\right)\\\\
&=\frac1{1001}\left(\frac{3B(B+1)}4-B(B+1)\right)\\\\
&=-\frac1{4004}B(B+1)\;.
\end{align*}$$

This is clearly maximized at $0$ when $B=0$.